# linux virtual networking with public ip

Tags: linux, networking

before i start i want to preemptively apologise, if this is stupid or too broad of a subject, i'm quite new to all of this stuff, i hope thats ok.

so, i have a vps from netcup and got assigned a public ipv4 lets call it `abc.def.183.90/22` with a gateway of `abc.def.180.1`

as this block clearly contains a lot of public ip addresses, i want to expose different services and docker containers using different public ip addresses. before anyone asks, yes a reverse proxy can also do a lot of that and i will be using multiple reverse proxies, but i do definitely need different public ips for some of the things i want to do.

after a couple hours of research, i've grasped the basic concepts of virtual networking in linux theoretically (i think), but i still don't have any idea where to start, so in desperation i've cone here and wanted to ask if anyone could steer me in the right direction or could recommend some great sources, where i can learn how to really do this stuff.

Comment: Typically with a VPS you get only a *single* IPv4 address  (from a within a larger subnet) not the complete subnet and the other IPv4 addresses in that subnet will be assigned to other customers. You'd need to pay extra for each additional IPv4 address to you want to get assigned and with any half-decent provider you can't go ahead and simply claim other IP-addresses

Comment: yes, typically that is the case, but if i'm not totally mistaken, netcup seems to really have assigned a /22 block to that vps. this is shown in the server control panel and 'ip addr' also returns 'abc.def.183.90/22'.

Comment: Context is everything. That should be read as *"the IP-address `abc.def.183.90` with the netmask of `255.255.252.0`  or `/22` "* . The complete subnet is the range `abc.def.180.0 - abc.def.183.255`  ; which in a different context and maybe confusingly you would also write as `abc.def.180.0/22`  - A quick look at https://www.netcup.eu/bestellen/produkt.php?produkt=2873 shows they charge you € 2,- per month for an additional IPv4 address and I doubt that you accidentally get  over € 2k worth of IPv4 addresses for free...

Comment: oh, ok. in that case i was just confused by netcups networking setup. i have never seen something like this with any other vps-provider.

Answer (score 0):

To build simple networks where hosts get internet routable IP addresses, implement IPv6. Route your prefix to your router, assign /64s to the virtual networks, and go for it.

IPv4 addresses are too expensive to do this with, unfortunately. Possibly you could build hosts IPv6 first, then proxy applications from a IPv4 service address to IPv6 backends. Where neither end to end v6 nor proxy works, use cases for additional IPv4 addresses need a reason for the expense.

Even with abundant address space this can get tricky. A typical rent a VM VPS provider won't route a /56 or a /64 to you, but creates a bunch of hosts on the same layer 2. NDP proxy can make your router respond to the neighbour solicitation anyway to work around this.